# Customizing Windows 8 Live Tiles

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

In Windows 8, the majority of my 'tiles' on my start screen (please correct my terminology if I'm misusing these) are not the fancy 'live tiles'.  They're just shortcuts to applications that will run on the desktop.

My question is, 'How can I customize their appearance'.  By default they are all forced to being the 'small' size and a background color of blue.  They seem to grab the default Icon but I'd like to be able to change the tile color/icon/size.

Is this possible?  If so - how do I do it?

Comment: This may help http://superuser.com/questions/495659/how-to-customize-tiles-change-bigger-icon-change-color-for-desktop-applicatio/521492#521492

Comment: That's excellent.  I'm a little sad it's not a part of Windows 8 - but that will do exactly what I want.  Thank you.  If you want to post that as an answer, I believe it's a good one.

Comment: OK and glad to be of help

Comment: If a question is the same as the previous one, it should be marked as a duplicate instead of duplicating the answers. You can `flag` your question for moderator attention if that's the case.

Comment: @slhck OK fine....