# Change icons for websites pinned to metro start menu

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have pinned a bunch of frequently used websites to my start menu, but now I would like to change each one's icon because they all look the same.

I know I can change programs icons, but how do you change the icon of several pinned websites?

Also, I'd like to be able to change the text for each one.

Comment: What method did you use pin them, and from which browser?

Comment: From IE, click the star, and then the Pin.  It will go to the Metro Start Menu.  This is what bugs me about Windows 8.  Things that were so intuitive in Windows 7 are difficult in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around finally!  But, it requires another program to do this.

[How to customize tiles (change/bigger icon, change color) for desktop applications in the Start Screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/495659/how-to-customize-tiles-change-bigger-icon-change-color-for-desktop-applicatio?rq=1)

This, combined with Start8 and Fences (by StarDock) makes Windows 8 usable.